# Renaming multiple files with variables split from file path and name via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a renaming script and a small part is causing me issues. I need to rename part of a jpg's filename with a split from the file's path.

Example of File:

```
"C:\WK53\WK5330002\WK44006679\spin1\01_img_0029.JPG"
```

In the above case I want to rename `01_img_0029.JPG` to `WK44006679_0029.JPG`, so replace string 0,1 of the filename with -3 of the file path.

I can derive the two portions of the name I want but I'm having trouble with the actual renaming logic. The following split isolates 'WK44006679' and the second isolates '0029':

```
$jpgToRename = GCI -Path $pathToRename -Filter '*.jpg' -R | ForEach-Object{
$newJpgASIN = $jpg.FullName.split('\')[-3]
$oldJpgName = $jpg.Name.split('_')[2]
}
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
$jpgToRename = GCI -Path $pathToRename -Filter '*.jpg' -R | ForEach-Object{
$newJpgASIN = $jpg.FullName.split('\')[-3]
$oldJpgName = $jpg.Name.split('_')[2]
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $oldJpgName,'_'+$newJpgASIN}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $oldJpgName,'_'+$newJpgASIN}` -> `Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace $oldJpgName, ('_'+$newJpgASIN))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$splitPath = ("C:\WK53\WK5330002\WK44006679\spin1\01_img_0029.JPG").Split("\\")

$newName = $splitPath[3] + ($splitPath[-1][2..($splitPath[-1].Length - 1)] -join "")
```

Comment: How do I pass each jpg in the directory thru this? I don't see a cmdlet that actually changes the name.

Comment: OK I understand now, for other users:
using my code above including the get-childitem bit, and substitute the Foreach-Object with a 'Foreach($jpg in $jpgToRename){} and replace $newJpgASIN and $oldJpgName with the above variables and use 'Rename-Item $jpg.FullName -NewName $newName'

Answer (score 1):

Minor change to the last suggestion from Jordan Regan.

```
$splitPath = ("C:\WK53\WK5330002\WK44006679\spin1\01_img_0029.JPG").Split("\\")

$YoMammy = -Join($splitPath[3],'_',$(($splitPath[-1]).split('_')[-1]))
```